# Android Crash Report

Tags: android

Hi
 what is the  the standard method new to Android 2.2 and an ad hoc method for older OS versions,  for sending crash report.

Comment: Here's similar earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378550/android-crash-reporting-library-pre-froyo Mentioned are android-remote-stacktrace, acra, Android-Error-Reporter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'd like to get the crash reports ACRA can be a good solution.ACRA is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their crash reports to a GoogleDoc form.Also Check this post [Android Production Logging Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050417/android-production-logging-best-practice) .

Comment: You could also try bugsense.com which can give you some extra details and visual reports

Answer (score 11):

I've been using [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) for crash reporting - they do some cool analytics for you and you don't need to setup your own server.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Zubhium for crash reporting, have a look. Does lot more than plain stack traces.